# Correct method for custom Rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes I currently have `resources :users` and so I get the routes such as `/users/id/` and `/users/id/edit` and so on...however, I am wanting to have the 'default' URLs for my pages begin with `/name` where `name` is the user's unique login name.

So, right now my routes file looks like this.

```
resources :users

match '/:name' => 'users#show_by_name'
```

Then in my users_controller.rb file, I have methods defined as such...

```
def show_by_name
  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
  render 'show'
end
```

So, basically it is doing the same thing as `def show` but instead of an `id` being passed in the URL, it's a name.

In my views I am linking like this...

```
<li><%= link_to "My Profile", "/#{current_user.name}" %></li>
```

As opposed to using `<li><%= link_to "My Profile", current_user %></li>`

I am wondering if I am going about this the correct way. I feel like I am doing something unnecessary by using extra methods in my users_controller.

Would I be better off just removing the `resources :users` line and creating my own routes that are more suited towards the type of URLs I want on my application?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off overriding the to_param method in your User model.  Rails has in built function for search friendly URL's

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     def to_param
        "#{user.name}"
     end
   end
```

Url's will generate as

```
user_url(@user)
#http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/andrew

# Controller
@user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
```

Comment: Would it be possible to also just skip having `/users/` in the URL?

Comment: Sure you could use a rout like Jef mentioned to then redirect to the show action in your Users controller : match '/:id' => 'users#show'

Comment: The URLs are generating fine, but then I get an error in my controllers saying, for example, `Couldn't find User with id=andrew`. Do I need to change my controller `@user = User.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: You still should have @user = User.find(params[:id]) in your controller.   Have you overridden the to_param method in User ?

Comment: Yeah. I was just watching a Railscast on the to_param method. It appears that using .find converts the argument passed to an integer? Therefore, if I'm not using something like `#{id} #{name}` then it's not finding an id. Changing all my User.find to User.find_by_name works now.

Comment: Ahh yes you are right,  you will need to have find_by_name.   http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use FriendlyID, it's a neat gem that translates the :id to a value based on one of the table's columns. This could be a title for instance or name in your case.

I found it fairly easy to start using.

Ryan Bates talks about it in this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

For installation look here: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: Very interesting! It seems like it works similarly to to_param.

Answer (score 1):

Both Andrew and Martin are right (the FriendlyID gem actually uses the to_param override method), but you're asking two questions :

- can I use another attribute instead of the default id as the id in the route ?
- can I use a non-resourceful route ?

In both cases, the answer is yes. You may override the `to_param` method AND use a non-REST route such as :

```
match '/:id' => 'users#show'
```

Comment: Works perfectly along with to_param override. Thanks!